# How to order list item and push something to the beginning of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I want to order my dynamic data so that if it includes a particular string, push it to the top of the list item. Then push the rest in. I'm confused about how to go about this.

So I have something like

So if it includes overview, push it to the front and rest push after. I'm kind of confused about how to do this.

Comment: Can you please post sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.sort() method

```js
const values = [
  { value: 'foo' },
  { value: 'bar' },
  { value: 'baz' },
  { value: 'overview' },
]

function toFront(arr, search) {
  return arr.sort(a => -a.value.includes(search))
}

console.log(toFront(values, 'overview'))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `reduce` in combination with the `unshift` and `push` methods to return a new Array that organizes itself based on whether or not the `value` of each object includes "overview":

```
tree.reduce( (acc, cv) => !cv.value.includes( "overview" ) ? 
   (acc.push(cv), acc) : 
   (acc.unshift(cv), acc ), []);
```

```js
//data setup
let tree = ["A","B","overview","C","D","overview","E","overview"].map(_=>Object({value:_}));

//result
let result = tree.reduce((acc, cv) => 
!cv.value.includes( "overview" ) ? 
(acc.push(cv), acc) : 
(acc.unshift(cv), acc ), []);

console.log( result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works to push anything with 'overview' to the front with the unshift call. You do not need the last push call as the array is modified in place with unshift.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` to populate two arrays, one for each category, and join them at the end:

```js
// Input
const tree = [{value: "A"},{value:"B"},{value:"overview"},{value:"C"},{value:"D"},{value:"overview"},{value:"E"},{value:"overview"}];

// Transformation
const result = [].concat(...tree.reduce(
    (acc, obj) => (acc[1-obj.value.includes("overview")].push(obj), acc),
    [[], []]
));

console.log( result);
```

Comment: So actually I have a function that is going over the array of objects. I want to check inside that function if the value of the current object it's iterating over is "overview" if it is, push it to the top.Push the rest after. if there is no overview than ignore. I'll update my code to show you what I am talking about

Comment: hi, I have updated my code. The part I need help on I put // in my code to indicate that's where I'd like to do the check.